# MongoDB: Remove "," from string, with conditional field set, in mixed datatype field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I am fairly new with MongoDB, so apologizes for what might be a basic question.

I have a bunch of documents in a collection (`call it CollA`), and taking a subset of it and the particular field in question would look like:

```
docs = [
{Value: "1,000,000+"},
{Value: "40,000"},
{Value: "2,000,000+"},
{Value: 500000},
{Value: 400000}]
```

*Note the mixed float and string datatypes within the field "Value".*

I am trying to find a way to:

1. Convert "Value" to a float (so I assume remove the "," and do a `$ToDouble` on it)
2. In the cases where the string contains a "+", I would like to set a new field "Truncated" to "true".

The desired output would be

```
docs = [
{Value: 1,000,000,
Truncated: true},
{Value: 40,000},
{Value: 2,000,000,
Truncated: true}},
{Value: 500000},
{Value: 400000}]
```

So now they would all be "doubles", and the new field would be there in the documents where the "+" existed.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- if not string (number) convert to double
- else(if string)
- split on + (first $let)
- save the first part, removing , and to double (second $let)
- if 2 parts add the first part and `Truncated`
- else add only the first part

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62d73675befa88fe45d75ed0)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$replaceRoot": 
   {"newRoot": 
     {"$cond": 
       [{"$not": [{"$eq": [{"$type": "$Value"}, "string"]}]},
         {"Value": {"$toDouble": "$Value"}},
         {"$let": 
           {"vars": {"parts": {"$split": ["$Value", "+"]}},
            "in": 
             {"$let": 
               {"vars": 
                 {"parts1": 
                   {"$toDouble": 
                     {"$replaceAll": 
                       {"input": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$$parts", 0]},
                        "find": ",",
                        "replacement": ""}}}},
                "in": 
                 {"$cond": 
                   [{"$arrayElemAt": ["$$parts", 1]},
                     {"Value": "$$parts1", "Truncated": true},
                     {"Value": "$$parts1"}]}}}}}]}}}])
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay getting back, was afk for a while.  This seems to be trying to create a new document?  as its throwing a key error

Comment: if you click on the link, it can run online, for those data it works, if you have data that give error if you canupdate your question, maybe missing fields? i dont know but for the data you sended i think query is ok

Comment: Ah, yeah I have a load of fields.  I ended up using a couple $sets in a row.  I used your logic for the conditions though, so that helped a lot.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$type](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) to differentiate strings vs numbers.
For string it's a combinations of if-else conditions, to add "Truncated" field,  remove non-number characters, and eventually convert to number with [$toDouble](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/).
The final $replaceWith is to bring additional fields to the root level:

```
db.colA.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      doc: {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $eq: [
              {
                "$type": "$Value"
              },
              "string"
            ]
          },
          "then": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$regexMatch": {
                  "input": "$Value",
                  "regex": "\\+$"
                }
              },
              "then": {
                "Value": {
                  "$toDouble": {
                    "$replaceAll": {
                      "input": {
                        "$replaceAll": {
                          "input": "$Value",
                          "find": "+",
                          "replacement": ""
                        }
                      },
                      "find": ",",
                      "replacement": ""
                    }
                  }
                },
                "Truncated": true,
                "original": "$Value"    // for debugging purposes
              },
              "else": {
                "original": "$Value",   // for debugging purposes
                "Value": {
                  "$toDouble": {
                    "$replaceAll": {
                      "input": "$Value",
                      "find": ",",
                      "replacement": ""
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "else": {
            "Value": "$Value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$doc"
  }
])
```

Comment: When I tried this, I ended up with a lot of blank dictionaries..

Comment: Then must be data was different to what you included in the question. I updated the query to include `original` Value - check what's there and adjust the script to handle these cases.  I hope the example provides clear idea how sting manipulation and data type conversion works - apply the same principle to handle all of your cases.